# docker: Error response from daemon: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apparmor

I install docker-ce 19.03.3, on ubuntu 19.04 following the installation procedure described on the official website. The installation worked well. But when I wanted to test by creating a container,

I have this error:

```
Error response from daemon: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded
```

running `/usr/sbin/apparmor_parser apparmor_parser -Kr /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default911109442`

failed with output:

```
'AppArmor parser error for /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-default911109442 in /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/global at line 17: Could not open 'tunables/proc'
```

`

Comment: The same issue has been fixed [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20554).

Answer (score 27):

Maybe you don't have AppArmor installed.

Try to do this:

```
apt install apparmor -y
```

Then restart the container.

Answer (score 12):

Installing the `apparmor-utils` package solved it for me

https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/23.0/#known-issues

Answer (score 5):

You have your answer in this docker issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20554

You just have to create this file: /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/proc

And put this line inside:

```
@{PROC}=/proc/
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I'm using Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838 on Debian 10.

Comment: another reason could be an unprivileged LXC container bein used to run docker - needs to be privileged

Answer (score 5):

I installed a new version of Linux Mint 20 Ulyana on a partition of a new drive (with my home directory synced to a different partition), and found Apparmor would not start, and docker would not run with any containers, not even hello_word. The errors all mentioned apparmor. I found that many of the files in

> /etc/apparmor.d/

had text to line 7, but showed binary symbols for line 7. I found that the config could be recreated by running:

> $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor

after which the config files in

> /etc/apparmor.d/

were all text. Then apparmor would start with

> $ /etc/init.d/apparmor restart

Then my docker containers ran again.

Answer (score 3):

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, just ran a 'apt update' then 'apt dist-upgrade', got a similar error starting docker.  Normally I remove apparmor, as was the case here. I had to re-install apparmor then remove it before docker containers would start.